# Could i recover MySql database?

Tags: mysql, windows-8, data-recovery

I formatted my windows 8, but I didn't save mysql database. Then I reinstalled a new windows and a new MySQL server. I found my old data table in the dump folder, but without the procedures I have created. Also, I found some files in the old windows folder which contains some of my procedures but not all. I still have the folder F:\Windows.old\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench. How can I recover my last version of my database with its procedures?

Comment: tbh I don't know that anyone in programming forums are going to spend the hour on it. I would check out stackexchange. Also there is decent info on the web about how to put files under the data hierarchy and slave away at it but it is terribly time-consuming

Comment: When was the last time you backed up your database ? And tested backup recovery ?

Comment: I did not make any back up! but the windows 8 shuld do a backup of the hole system befor formatting the PC and put it in a folder named Windows.old. my question is that: Do Mysql save automaticaly the procedure we create? It shuld save it otherwise we can not see our work after restart the PC. So where MySQL save procedures we create?

Comment: Drew Pierce, My problem is that i can not found the files of my last updated database!